# grab value of div using class

Tags: javascript, jquery

Inside div i set a value now i want to grab this value using class. But code bellow not returns the value. Whats wrong i am doing here? how can i solve that?

```
<div title="Find on Amazon" value="352197909440" class="btn btn-default btnAmazon" style="padding-top:5px !important" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#FindOnAmazonModal">
  <i class="fa fa-bullseye"></i> 
</div>
```

```js
$(".btnAmazon").on("click", function () {
  var d = $(".btnAmazon").val();
  alert(d);
});
```

Comment: Note that `div` elements do not have a `value` attribute. By creating your own you've made your HTML non-standard which may lead to other HTML or JS issues. If you want to store custom meta data with an element, use a `data-*` attribute, as you already are, and use `.data('value')` to retrieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think "value" as a attribute is not allowed on div elements. 
Try it like this:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(".btnAmazon").on("click", function () {
      var d = $(this).attr("data-value");
      alert(d);
    });
});
```

```css
.btn{
  background: green;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align:center;
  display:inline-block;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div title="Find on Amazon" data-value="352197909440" class="btn btn-default 
       btnAmazon" data-toggle="modal" data-
       target="#FindOnAmazonModal">
       <i class="fa fa-bullseye"></i> 
       Button
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

> Inside div i set a value now i want to grab this value using class

Looks like you are are looking for `value` attribute of `div`

`val()` is for input elements, replace it with `attr( "value" )`

```
var d = $(".btnAmazon").attr( "value" );
```

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to read the div's "value" *attribute*.

```js
console.log($('div').val()) // This won't work; DIVs don't have a value
console.log($('div').attr('value')) // but this one has an attribute named value
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div title="Find on Amazon" value="352197909440" class="btn btn-default btnAmazon" style="padding-top:5px !important" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#FindOnAmazonModal">
  <i class="fa fa-bullseye"></i> 
</div>
```

Note that, strictly speaking, `value` is not a valid attribute -- ever since the XHTML era, nonstandard attributes are supposed to have a `data-` or `x-` prefix -- but it will work just fine in all browsers.  If code validation is a concern, the "correct" way to handle this would be:

```js
// either of these will work, interchangeably:
console.log($("div").data("value")) 
console.log($("div").attr("data-value"))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div title="Find on Amazon" data-value="352197909440" class="btn btn-default btnAmazon" style="padding-top:5px !important" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#FindOnAmazonModal">
  <i class="fa fa-bullseye"></i> 
</div>
```

Comment: My point is that it's a non-standard attribute which can cause issues as the HTML is no longer valid. using `data-*` attributes is a better solution, which the OP is already doing, except for this attribute for some inexplicable reason.

Comment: @Rory it's not logically the same. `.val()` probably references the object by saying `DOMElement.value` and `.attr('value')` actually looks for an attribute called value

Answer (score 2):

I could see that you want to read the `value` attribute, which cannot be used for `<div>` tag. Please use either `data-value`:

```
data-value="396495"
```

And get it using:

```
.data("value");
```

This is the right method. Using `.attr("value")` might work in some browsers and not sure if it works seamlessly everywhere. But that's what you need.

Comment: @DanielBeck Looks so... `:(`

Comment: didn't downvote but I think it's because OP wants to read "value" attribute from the DIV element and not it's content/text

Comment: @ꜱᴜʀᴇꜱʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ Updated the answer.

Comment: @Ezenhis Updated the answer.

Comment: @DanielBeck Updated the answer.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have updated my answer as well to include the necessary details.

Comment: FWIW I'd suggest removing the initial off-target portion of the answer (because it's unrelated to the question, and contains borderline-incorrect information in that it implies that `.text` and `.html` are almost interchangeable)...

Comment: @DanielBeck Done... Removed.

Answer (score 0):

In order to retrieve to attribute named value (the 352197909440 in your example) you will need to use

```
var d = $(".btnAmazon").attr('value');
```

.html() will show you the html within your Div. i.e.

```
<i class="fa fa-bullseye"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

A `div` can't have a `value` attribute, it is invalid markup.

You, however, can use custom [`data-*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) attributes (as you already use in your code).

So first of change your HTML

```
<div title="Find on Amazon" data-value="352197909440" class="btn btn-default btnAmazon" style="padding-top:5px !important" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#FindOnAmazonModal">
  <i class="fa fa-bullseye"></i> 
</div>
```

Then you can use `$('.btnAmazon').data('value')` to get its value...

Working example:

```js
$(".btnAmazon").on("click", function () {
  var d = $(".btnAmazon").data('value');
  alert(d);
});
```

```css
/* for the demo */
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div title="Find on Amazon" data-value="352197909440" class="btn btn-default btnAmazon" style="padding-top:5px !important" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#FindOnAmazonModal">
  <i class="fa fa-bullseye"></i> 
</div>
```